# What is the different between "sudo su" and "sudo bash"？

Tags: bash, sudo, su

In Ubuntu 13.10, for the default setting, the following command in `Terminal`

```
user@host:~/path$ sudo su
```

results in entering an prompt

```
root@host:/home/user/path#
```

And this command

```
user@host:~/path$ sudo bash
```

enters prompt

```
root@host:~/path#
```

Is this means a different between those two commands to be that `~` have different meaning?

Usually I use `sudo` only. But sometimes it is not enough. For example if I wanted to write a command that modifies some file with `cat >> file <<EOF`, and the file is only writeable for `root`, I have to either use `sudo su` or `sudo bash`(assume `bash` is your preferred shell). But the above example seems to show that use `sudo bash` is better because the operation environment is more like the previous one. Is this the case? What else are different between those commands?

Comment: You can use `sudo tee` for redirection with `sudo` rights.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: @AvinashRaj The website only shows how to work with simple redirections like `ls > out`, but not for two way redirections as in my case. So can you or @DanielAndersson show me how to use `sudo tee` in this case?

Comment: `~` represents your `$HOME` directory.

Comment: Also, in most of the cases, I wanted to copy and paste some command lines from some web page. Usually they are assuming you are `root` but in most cases I only need to prefix it with `sudo`. If it is not always easy to show how to replace a redirection command with `sudo tee`, I would rather enter `sudo bash` or `sudo su` and paste those commands.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Just write `cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a file`, followed by content and a new `EOF`. Your order works as well. Also, the FAQ linked by @AvinashRaj explains the difference in `sudo su` and `sudo bash` further down: [Special notes on sudo and shells](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells)

Comment: @DanielAndersson That notes contains a table that lists the difference. However I don't think it represents the case in Ubuntu 13.10. It says `HOME=/root` to be `N` in both `sudo su` and `sudo bash`, but actually for the former it should be `Y`. Also `$PATH` in both cases are different from the user's, and different from each other.

Comment: If you have GNU `dd` then you can `sudo dd of=file oflag=append conv=notrunc <<EOF`. (Posix standard `dd` only allows `seek=`, which can only be specified in complete blocks, making it difficult to seek to the end of the output file.)